# Getting unexpected output

Tags: c, arrays

Can anyone please help me understand how the output is `3 2 15` for the following code?

I am expecting output as: `2 2 15` because

- first the element `a[1]` i.e `1` will get pre-incremented and `i` will be assigned `2`,
- then `j` will also be assigned `2` because post increment is done and,
- when it comes to `m`, `a[i++]` should be as `a[2]` i.e `15`, since post increment is done and `m` should be assigned `15`.

Please help me if I am wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5]={5,1,15,20,25};
    int i,j,m;
    i=++a[1];
    j=a[1]++;
    m=a[i++];
    printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Different output" means *different than you expect*? Then please add to your post what you expect (and why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second menber of your array is 1.
So doing i=++a[1]; translates to i=++1;.
this is 2.
J is the same thing ( in this case ).
Then you take out the second value of your array (15) with "i" which is two, then you add one to "i".
Resulting in i=3, j=2 and m=15.

Note : i=++1; is just to visualize what is happening, this shouldn't and can't be used.

Answer (score 4):

```
int a[5]={5,1,15,20,25};
```

Increment `a[1]` to `2`, and set `i` to that

```
i=++a[1];
```

Set `j` to `a[1]` (2), *then* increment `a[1]` to 3

```
j=a[1]++;
```

set `m` to `a[i]` (`a[2]`, or 15), *then* increment `i` to 3

```
m=a[i++];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    i=++a[1]; /* a[1] = 1 and you have a pre-increment so */

    i = 2;

    j = a[1]++; /* a[1] = 2  and post-increment so j = 2 */

    j= 2

    m=a[i++]; /* m = a[2] = 15 and `i` is incremented later i = 3 */

    m = 15

    i = 3

So i=3 j = 2 and m = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

- a[1] get incremented to 2; i gets assigned this value
- the value of a[1] (still 2) also gets assigned to j, after which a[1] gets incremented to 3
- a[2] (15) gets assigned to m; then i gets incremented to 3

Answer (score 0):

```
a[1]=1;
i=++a[1]; //a[1] is pre-incremented by 1 so i=2;
j=a[1]++; // a[1] is post incremented by 1 so j=2;
m=a[i++]; // i is post incremented by 1  so m =a[2] so m=15
          // as i was post incremented so i=2+1 in next step.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=++a[1]; ==> ++a[1] == 2
```

`i` gets the value of pre incremented of array `a[1]`, which is `2`

```
j=a[1]++; ==> a[1]++ == 2
```

Similarly `j` becomes `2` but post incremented.

```
m=a[i++]; ==> a[3] == 15 /* Here i became 3*/
```

Here first `i` which is already `2` incremented by `1` becoming `3` which is post incremented in next statement, resulting `m` gets assigned with `a[2]` which is `15`.

Comment: Your edit was in grace time period. I can't retract my vote. Edit it with some explanation.